# JdbcSQLException on Tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, maven, jdbc

I have a GWT/GXT application that runs fine via "gwt:run" (hosted mode) but on the Tomcat server it crashes with an `JdbcSQLException`, which I don't understand because the call leading to the exception is server code that isn't translated to javascript anyways. Also I didn't write the code that causes the exception myself, it is contained in a library that is used by my application.

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?

P.S.: Per request here the code statement that throws the exception:

```
private Connection conn;
[...]
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:"+databaseDirectory+"/"+databaseName+jdbcString, "sa", "");
[...]
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM QUERY_CACHE WHERE QUERYHASH=? LIMIT 1"); // throws the exception
```

The full stack trace:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "unexpected status 7274613" [90067-143]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:558)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.prepare(CommandRemote.java:68)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.<init>(CommandRemote.java:47)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.prepareCommand(SessionRemote.java:421)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1052)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:233)
    at org.dllearner.kb.sparql.ExtractionDBCache.executeSelectQuery(ExtractionDBCache.java:183)
    at org.dllearner.kb.sparql.ExtractionDBCache.executeSelectQuery(ExtractionDBCache.java:174)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.executeSelectQuery(SPARQLReasoner.java:887)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.getSubClasses(SPARQLReasoner.java:766)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.getSubClasses(SPARQLReasoner.java:745)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.prepareSubsumptionHierarchy(SPARQLReasoner.java:124)
    at org.dllearner.algorithm.tbsl.learning.SPARQLTemplateBasedLearner.setEndpoint(SPARQLTemplateBasedLearner.java:229)
    at org.autosparql.server.search.TBSLSearch.getExamples(TBSLSearch.java:117)
    at org.autosparql.server.search.TBSLSearch.getExamples(TBSLSearch.java:105)
    at org.autosparql.server.AutoSPARQLSession.getExamples(AutoSPARQLSession.java:354)
    at org.autosparql.server.AutoSPARQLServiceImpl.getExamples(AutoSPARQLServiceImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.dllearner.kb.sparql.SparqlQuery.convertJSONtoResultSet(SparqlQuery.java:297)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.executeSelectQuery(SPARQLReasoner.java:887)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.getSubClasses(SPARQLReasoner.java:766)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.getSubClasses(SPARQLReasoner.java:745)
    at org.dllearner.reasoning.SPARQLReasoner.prepareSubsumptionHierarchy(SPARQLReasoner.java:124)
    at org.dllearner.algorithm.tbsl.learning.SPARQLTemplateBasedLearner.setEndpoint(SPARQLTemplateBasedLearner.java:229)
    at org.autosparql.server.search.TBSLSearch.getExamples(TBSLSearch.java:117)
    at org.autosparql.server.search.TBSLSearch.getExamples(TBSLSearch.java:105)
    at org.autosparql.server.AutoSPARQLSession.getExamples(AutoSPARQLSession.java:354)
    at org.autosparql.server.AutoSPARQLServiceImpl.getExamples(AutoSPARQLServiceImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: can you show some code? it's hard to imagine what are you wrong there

Comment: Looks like your physical connection is been reset for some reason, monitor the packet to/fro your adaptor using either wireshark or tcpdump to see if it give you any clues.

Comment: I don't think it's the physical connection, because I tried it several times locally and it worked and I tried it several times on the tomcat and it didn't.

Comment: @c0mrade: OK, I added the code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Is this "org.dllearner.kb.sparql.SparqlQuery.convertJSONtoResultSet" your code or are you using third party API

Comment: it's a third party API but I know the people who wrote it.